# Angular JWT token parsing to json issue

Tags: json, angular, api, jwt

I have validated my JWT on jwt.io 
[image]

But when i try to parse the response to:

```
  login(model: any) {
return this.http
  .post(this.baseURI + 'login', model, this.requestOptions())
  .map((response: Response) => {
    const user = response.json();
    if (user) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
      this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(user.token);
      console.log(this.decodedToken);
      this.userToken = user.token;
    }
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

it throws an error stating:

[image]

Error is generated when it tries to parse response to json: **response.json();**
A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Angular is running in the development mode..." is not an error, it is just an information message telling you that Angular is running in dev mode. If you do "ng serve --prod" instead of just "ng-serve" you will see that it will not say that.

Comment: Attached the wrong image. Please see the error now.

Comment: remove this.requestOptions() please

Comment: requestoptions are the header options.

Comment: Can you please specify your response text?

Comment: There should not be a requirement to parse/decode a `jwt` at client side. You should store it as it's and share with each http request to validate your user

Answer (score 0):

Since the token starts with `e` and your error states that its getting an unexpected `e` at position 0 of what it expects to be a Json document, it sounds like you might be getting a response body including the token as raw *text*, not the Json `User` object which your code expects.